# How to extract a specific text from a string. The hard part is the desired text changes periodically

Tags: javascript, c#, html, string

I have an HTML document which contains this text somewhere in it

```
function deleteFolder() {
        var mailbox = "CN=John Urban,OU=Sect-1,DC=TestServer ,DC=acme,DC=com";
        var path = "/Inbox/";

//string of interest: "CN=John Urban,OU=Sect-1,DC=TestServer ,DC=acme,DC=com"
```

I just want to extract this text and store it in a variable in C#. My problem is that string of interest will slightly change each time the page is loaded, something like this:

- "CN=John Urban,OU=Sect-1,DC=TestServer ,DC=acme,DC=com"
- "CN=Jane Doe,OU=Sect-1,DC=TestServer ,DC=acme,DC=com"
- etc....

How do I extract that ever changing string, without regular expression?

Comment: Without regular expression? Why in gods name?

Comment: @JonathanBrooks I was told not to use regular expression, unless I absolutely have to. I was wondering if there was a way, like  a built in function that does that.

Comment: Can you change that delete function? I would make an ajax call and store it, or set a hidden field with that value so I can get it from the backend.

Comment: @JonathanBrooks I'm just a junior software dev, stuck with a hard problem.

Comment: @AAlferez I have no control over the front end. It's legacy code.

Comment: Is the text always in that line? "var mailbox = "CN=John Urban,OU=Sect-1,DC=TestServer ,DC=acme,DC=com";"
What if you check htmlCode.indexOf("var mailbox");?
Is that string always assigned to that var?

Comment: @AAlferez yes, everything else stays the same except the first name and last name will change

Comment: Seems like someone answered what I'm telling you, find the index of "var mailbox" and you know that the next 2 double quotes contains your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it always a function `deleteFolder()` which has its first line as `var mailbox = "somestring"`? And you are interested in `somestring`?

Based on the requirements you told us, could just search your string containing the HTML for `var mailbox ="` and then the next `"` and take all text between these two occurrences.

```
var htmlstring= "..."; //
var i1 = htmlstring.IndexOf("var mailbox = \"");
var i2 = i1 >= 0 ? htmlstring.IndexOf("\"", i1+15) : -1;
var result = i2 >= 0 ? htmlstring.Substring(i1+15, i2-(i1+15)): "not found";
```

VERY, VERY ugly, not maintainable, but without more information, I can't do any better. However Regex would be much nicer!

Comment: OMG! After some slight adjustments, it works perfectly. Thank you so much for the help.